# Unable to delete a polygon on a bing Map Wpf control, cast exception

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-api, bing-maps

I'm using the bing map wpf control.

I add some polygon like this :

```
        polygon.Locations = DrawACircle(oLoc, dRadius);
        polygon.Tag = "Circle";
        MyMapUserControl.MyMap.Children.Add(polygon);
```

With this, my polygon are correctly displaying.

Now, i would like to delete this polygon ( i can have severals polygon, that's why i use a tag : "Circle" ), i tried this :

```
var polygonToDelete = MyMapUserControl.MyMap
                              .Children
                              .OfType<MapPolygon>()
                              .Where(p => ((MapPolygon)p).Tag == "Circle");

MyMapUserControl.MyMap.Children.Remove((UIElement)polygonToDelete);
```

I have an exception with a cast error.

Anyone coud help me please ?

Best regards,

Comment: Maybe you could copy past the error message? This would help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when using lambda expressions, you can't cast like this. You should use the safe cast and an handle errors in an better way.

Answer (score 1):

Using a break point check to see what the value is of the polygonToDelete object is before it calls the remove method. Is it a single shape or a collection of shapes? I suspect that it is a collection of shapes and you need to grab the first one, or convert your object to a List and loop through each item and remove it from the map.

Try something like this:

```
var polygonToDelete = MyMap.Children.OfType<MapPolygon>()
                    .Where(p => ((MapPolygon)p).Tag == "Circle").ToList();

foreach (var p in polygonToDelete)
{
    MyMap.Children.Remove(p);
}
```